# Mac unable to browse to any websites hosted at a single IP

Tags: macos, networking, dns, browser, web

I am unable to browse to any websites that are hosted on a single IP address - a reseller web hosting account that I manage, with a number of websites on it. This occurs in all browsers. Other websites are fine. The issue is just with websites hosted at this reseller account.

Errors:

*Safari:*

```
Safari can’t open the page XXXXXXXX because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection.
This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.
```

*Chrome:*

```
No data received
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
```

*Firefox:*

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

I am able to SSH, ping, traceroute, etc to the IP address. I can even log into the reseller hosting control panel (WHM) which runs on a different port - it is purely a web browsing issue on port 80.

Other machines at the same connection as me have no problems - just my machine.

I have tried many different things to resolve this:

- Using different DNS (Google, OpenDNS, etc.)
- Flushing DNS cache
- Clearing of cache in all browsers
- Used both WiFi and LAN connections

If I connect my machine to a personal hotspot on my phone, I am able to browse to these sites no problems. Switching back to my office network, and the issue is back. This may suggest it is the office connection being blocked, however:

- There are other machines on this network that can access the same sites perfectly fine
- There are no blocks at the web host for this IP

I have checked with the Hosting Provider, and they can see no issues at their end.

My machine:

Mac Yosemite 10.10.4
Broswers: Safari (8.0.7 (10600.7.12)), Chrome (44.0.2403.107 (64-bit)), Firefox (39.0)

So, I am putting this weird issue out there in the hope that somebody has some ideas on what may be the cause of the problem.

Looking forward to some ideas.

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: if You go to system preferences -> Network, is the DNS server ip address the same as on the other machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to dig a bit further, and found the following entries in the system.log:

```
acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:47 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Caught exception. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:47 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Failed to connect externally. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:48 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:48 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Caught exception. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:48 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Failed to connect externally. Code : 60
Jul 29 12:53:51 zzzz.local acwebsecagent[257]: Connection : Auth key is not provided or is invalid, applying connection failure policy. CMode : 2 TMode : 1
```

Turns out, these errors were being logged by the **CISCO AnyConnect application**.

I no longer use this application, so have **removed it**, and it appears (so far) that the issue has been resolved.

If I still needed to use this application, it is possible to disable the Web Security filtering:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin30/ac06websecurity.html#pgfId-1043003

```
Disabling and Enabling Filters Using Mac OS X

The service password used in this procedure is configured in the Authentication panel of the Web Security profile editor.

Step 1 Launch the Terminal application.

Step 2 Change to the /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin folder.

Step 3 Disable or enable filtering:

To enable filtering, enter acwebsecagent -enablesvc
To disable filtering, enter acwebsecagent -disablesvc -servicepassword
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I had the same problem and have been baffled by it for a while now.  Happened upon this question and it turned out I had installed CISCO AnyConnect as a VPN for my university account.  For some reason the Web Security component was enabled and had begun blocking this mundane site.  I was unable to disable it as it required a password and I'd never set one, but uninstalling worked for me.  Thanks!